# django language translation using i18n for xml parsed content

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization, django-i18n

This is my settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
('ar',    ugettext('Arabic (U.A.E.)')),
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

This is my xml file. I want to translate the header tag content i.e "hello" as "مرحبا"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<node id="1">
    <header>hello</header>
</node>
<node id="2">
    <header>hi</header>
</node>
<node id="3">
    <header>how are you?</header>
</node>
</xml>
```

Below is the function in views.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
def header_display(request):
    xml_dictionary = {}
    xml_dictionary ['xml'] = {}
    preso = etree.parse(file_path)
    root = preso.getroot()
    nodes = root.findall('node')
    for node in nodes:
        node_id = int(node.attrib["id"])
        xml_dictionary['xml'][node_id] = {}
        head_tag= node.find('header')
        header = head_tag.text
        head_val=_('%(header)s')% {'header': header}
        xml_dictionary['xml'][node_id]['head']={}
        xml_dictionary['xml'][node_id]['head']['value']=head_val
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'xml':xml_dictionary})
```

Below is template for index.html

```
<html>
{% load i18n %}
<title></title>
<body>
 {% for key,value in xml.items %}
     {% for id,attribs in value.items %}
         {% if attribs.head.value %}
         <h2>{% blocktrans with header=attribs.head.value %}{{ header }}{% endblocktrans %}</h2>
         {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed the preferred-languages setting in mozilla as "Arabic/U.A.E" (under Tools->Options->Content->Languages in Firefox) .But still it displays as hi, hello, how are you. And the below is my django.po for "ar" in locale\ar\LC_MESSAGES\django.po

```
#: .\views.py:15
#: .\templates\index.html.py:7
#, python-format
msgid "%(header)s"
msgstr ""
```

Comment: your msgstr appears to be empty

Comment: header in msgid is dynamic and keeps on changing. I cannot add one specific translated string ex:"مرحبا" in msgtr. Can you help me out with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your `django.po` file translations of `hello`, `hi` and so on with

```
msgid "hello"
msgstr "مرحبا"

msgid "hi"
msgstr "<whatever>"
```

and use them in template with

```
<h2>{% trans attribs.head.value %}</h2>
```

Comment: @sorab so it means translation don't work, probably issue in your settings/config.

Comment: translation works fine. I have added <title>{% trans "Content" %}</title>, which is working fine. And i am using translation at many places, its all working fine.But not in the above context.

Comment: @sorab and what about `<title>{% trans "hello" %}</title>`

Comment: attribs.head.value is in forloop and contains "hello", "hi", "how are you?", which should be translated to arabic. Ofcourse {% trans "hello" %} is translated but it is static content not dynamic.

Comment: @sorab there might be some additional chars in your value, such as `\n`, `\t`, ` ` etc, that's why I ask about static translation. that should work seamlessly in case dynamic value **equals** some of statics.

Answer (score -1):

`msgstr` should be set as `"مرحبا"`  in **locale\ar\LC_MESSAGES\django.po**

It should be -:

```
#: .\views.py:15
#: .\templates\index.html.py:7
#, python-format
msgid "%(header)s"
msgstr "مرحبا"
```

And then run command `python manage.py compilemessages`

Comment: You mentioned it for "hello". But what about "hi", "how are you" from xml?

Comment: This will not work for dynamic content.. you need to use django translation packages for this..

Comment: can you suggest me any django translation package for dynamic content?

Comment: I did not down vote. First of all i do not have privilege to down vote because i am new to stackoverflow and new to development.